# One Match for specific words

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem matching one single word. I'm making a slack bot but I have some difficulties using regex, here is the code that brokes my program:

```
@listen_to(r'(?:\W|^)(CTRG|Viper)(?:\W|$)', re.IGNORECASE)
def refme_send(message):
    sleep(1)
    answers = ('You\'re not supposed to talk about it.', 'This information is classified!')
    message.send(answers[randrange(0, len(answers))])
```

And this is the error I get while testing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/my_user/.slack/SlackBot/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slackbot/dispatcher.py", line 55, in _dispatch_msg_handler
    func(Message(self._client, msg), *args)
TypeError: hello_reply() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the regex on the first line? Try `r'(?i)\b(CTRG|Viper)\b'`

Comment: What's `hello_reply`?

Comment: Problem still present. But thank you for this alternative regex code!

Comment: Same as refme_send(), I have various functions that fails, I don't took the error corresponding with the function in the example (my bad). Anyway I have exactly the same with refme_send()

Comment: Try `@listen_to(r'(?i)\b(CTRG|Viper)\b')`. When you want to notify a user, add `@`+username to your comment.

Comment: Finally I found a dirty solution, it's not the best way to fix it but it works: `def refme_send(*messages)` and then using `messages[0]` instead of message. The use of a tulp (list) avoid errors when multiple parameters are sent to the function.